# NAudio is not reading MemoryStream containing wav data

Tags: c#, .net, wav, naudio, memorystream

I'm trying to use NAudio to record 8 seconds of streaming audio, store it in `System.IO.MemoryStream`, and then play it back right after. To do this, I'm running the following code:

```
using System.IO;
using NAudio.Wave;

public class AudioCapture{

    static WaveFileWriter wri;
    static bool stopped = false;

    public AudioCapture(){
        //record from loopback
        IWaveIn waveIn = new WasapiLoopbackCapture();
        waveIn.DataAvailable += waveIn_DataAvailable;
        waveIn.RecordingStopped += waveIn_RecordingStopped;

        //write loopback capture to MemoryStream
        Stream sos = new MemoryStream();
        wri = new WaveFileWriter(sos, waveIn.WaveFormat);

        //record 8 seconds of streaming audio
        waveIn.StartRecording();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(8000);
        waveIn.StopRecording();

        //flush and dispose objects
        wri.Flush();
        waveIn.Dispose();
        wri.Dispose();

        //play back recorded audio
        WaveOut waveOut = new WaveOut();
        WaveFileReader waveFileReader = new WaveFileReader(sos);
        waveOut.Init(waveFileReader);
        waveOut.Play();

    }

    static void waveIn_RecordingStopped(object sender, StoppedEventArgs e){
        stopped = true;
    }

    static void waveIn_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e){
        if (wri != null) wri.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
    }

}
```

I get the following exception telling me that the stream could not be read:

```
Activated   Event   Time    Duration    Thread
    Exception: Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in NAudio.dll 
("Stream was not readable."). Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in 
NAudio.dll ("Stream was not readable.") 17.86s      [17404] <No Name>
```

I'm not quite sure what the issue is as WaveFileWriter clearly accepts `MemoryStream` according to the documentation. Is there some conversion that I'm missing? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

For clarification: The error seems to be at this line:

```
WaveFileReader waveFileReader = new WaveFileReader(sos);
```

Comment: Most likely, `sos` is getting disposed when you dispose `wri`

Comment: If I switch the order of the dispose and playback blocks, I get this error instead: `/Activated Event Time Duration Thread
 Exception: Exception thrown: 'System.IO.EndOfStreamException' in NAudio.dll ("Unable to read beyond the end of the stream."). Exception thrown: 'System.IO.EndOfStreamException' in NAudio.dll ("Unable to read beyond the end of the stream.") 9.26s  [21768] <No Name> 
`

Comment: Don't dispose `wri` and after recording rewind memory stream: `sos.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`

Comment: @Evk Wow this totally solved it. Thanks so much! Care to post it as an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WaveFileWriter` is (unfortunately) designed in a way that it *always* disposes stream it writes to when you dispose `WaveFileWriter`. It could have accepted some flag to control this behavior, but it does not. So if you need to use that stream later you need to either not dispose `WaveFileWriter` too early, or clone that closed memory stream. If you choose to not dispose writer - you need to rewind memory stream back to position 0, so that reading can start from the beginning (after writing position is at the end):

```
wri.Flush();
waveIn.Dispose();
// wri.Dispose(); < too early
sos.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

If you want to use a clone - rewind is not needed:

```
wri.Flush();
waveIn.Dispose();
wri.Dispose();
sos = new MemoryStream(sos.ToArray());
```

Drawback of cloning is that it creates unnecessary copy of the whole byte array (`ToArray` call).

Comment: Great explanation. Cheers mate!

Comment: Rewind won't work in this context as the `Dispose` is needed to fix up WAV headers (n.b. `Flush` can also do that in latest version of NAudio). NAudio does have a helper called `IgnoreDisposeStream` you can wrap your memory stream in if you really want to write a WAV file to a `MemoryStream`, but if you're not going to disk, introducing the WAV file format is unnecessary. I've added another answer showing how to do this without WAV.

Comment: @MarkHeath but doesn't `Flush()` fixes up those headers?

Comment: yes you're right, I did update my comment to say that - was a fairly recent addition to NAudio, so rewind after flush also works, but still introducing WAV file format is pointless in these scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `WaveFileReader` or `WaveFileWriter` in this scenario. Just write the audio received to the `MemoryStream` as it arrives:

```
static void waveIn_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e){
    if (sos != null) sos.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
}
```

And then when you've finished and are ready to play, rewind the `MemoryStream` and play using a `RawSourceWaveStream`:

```
//play back recorded audio
var waveOut = new WaveOut();
sos.Position = 0;
var waveFileReader = new RawSourceWaveStream(sos, waveIn.WaveFormat);
waveOut.Init(waveFileReader);
waveOut.Play();
```